# VBA code to extract form data from Word to Excel. Suddenly the code not longer works, but there is not error or bug message, why?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, export-to-excel

I set up the code below several months ago and tested it, and had colleagues test it and it was working fine. I have just opened it and it no longer works, but I am not getting an alert of any error or bug. The macro runs and I can see the relevant cells being formatted (i.e. the final part of the code), but MS Word does not appear to open at any point. I set up a simple "Document.Open" sub to check that Excel was still working with Word, and that was fine. Can anyone help?

N.B. (1) I have redacted the specifics in the following, but have checked that the folder directories and file names are correct.

N.B. (2) I have recently moved from Windows 2010 and the associated Office applications to 365. However, we currently have both system running concurrently and the problem seems to appear on both.

N.B. (3) The code is current a Private Sub attached to an control button, but even when put into a Module it does not work.

N.B. (4) if I Step In with F8 it gets stuck as "wdApp.Quit" and I have to close Excel through Task Manager, but there is still no error alert.

N.B. (5) I removed the instructions to close and quit Word and there does not appear to be any instance of Word open according to task manager.

Please help:-)

Code:

```
Private Sub REDACTEDTITLE_Click()

Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim myForm As Word.Document
Dim CCtl As Word.ContentControl
Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long

myFolder = "R:\REDACTED_FOLDER_PATH"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If myFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Data").Select
Set myWorksheet = ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Range("B13:CB27").Clear

i = myWorksheet.Cells(13, 2).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)

While strFile <> ""
i = i + 1

Set myForm = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

With myForm
j = 1
For Each CCtl In .contentcontrols
j = j + 1
myWorksheet.Cells(i, j) = CCtl.Range.Text

Next

End With

myForm.Close SaveChanges:=False
strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set myForm = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set myWorksheet = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Range("B13:CB27").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Range("B13:CB27").VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range("B13:CB27").WrapText = True
Range("B13:CB27").Interior.Color = RGB(197, 220, 243)
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("B13:CB27").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

Comment: You never set the `Visible` property of `WdApp` to `True`, so you shouldn't expect to see it in the UI

Comment: Many thanks. Good point. I would normally expect to see Word flicker, as it is pinned to the task bar. However, I have run the code with ScreenUpdating and Visible set to "True" as well, as well as AddToRecentFiles set to True and there is no evidence that Word has run at any point. I am starting to think that there is an issue with some of my setting rather than there being a problem with the code. We use adapted versions of this macro for various projects and none of them is working. Are there setting I would to look at.

Comment: In any event, the data is not appearing in Excel as it should.

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code in your `For Each` loop, paying particular attention to the _Locals Window_, i.e. expand the `CCtl` node, scroll down to its `Range` property, then the `Text` property of that, and confirm whether it is what you expect it to be

Comment: Many thanks for looking at this again. When I step into the code and tab through with F8 it skips from While strFile <> "" to wdApp.Quit . Does that mean that it is not recognising the fiels saved in the destination folder? I have not changed the format or name of the files since the code was working as expected. Please bear with me, I am self taught in VBA so have very large gaps in my knowledge. Do I need to use cide to expand the CCtl node, how would I do this?

Comment: Yes, that means its not recognising any files (so there's no point looking at the CCtl node). In _Windows Explorer_, I would suggest that you browse to the targeted folder, select one of the .docx files, on the _Home_ tab of the ribbon, click on _Copy Path_ to copy the full filename of the selected file to the clipboard and then, in notepad or somewhere else, paste it, and compare that text with the value of `myFolder`

Comment: Thank you. That has solved it. I thought I had checked this, I had checked it, but obviously made a mistake. In my panic I must have missed the difference in the long path text. Many thanks for your help. What a basic mistake:-( Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!